# Refused to display 'google oauth2' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-account

I have a simple public ***site A*** that gets data from ***site B*** with is private (user can access it using google account -> 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/).
This is for testing purposes.

I can access the data on ***site A*** while in browser with my google account, respectively cannot in incognito view. It was great but I need to **test on real device mobile and it's a problem**. Even though I am in my google account I get error `Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/..' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.`
I read several articles and added these to my code

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*"); ?>
<?php header("X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN"); ?> (or ALLOW-FROM etc)
```

But it did not help.
My question is, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it helps someone else.

So the problem was in the mobile browser (Safari) which does not share cookies between pages.
I solved it just disabling `Prevent Cross-Site Tracking` on my iPhone and it allowed me to authorised on one page and get that cookies on another page. As it works on PC browsers version.
[image]